# What is temporal difference learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

While reading about reinforcement learning, I saw that this is a prediction method, somewhat similar to Monte Carlo.

What is an example of it?

Answer (score 3):

Information on Temporal Difference (TD) learning is widely available on the internet, although [David Silver's lectures](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching.html) are (IMO) one of the best ways to get comfortable with the material.

In TD learning, the Q-values are updated after each iteration throughout an epoch, instead of only updating the values at the end of the epoch, as happens in Monte Carlo learning. A more intermediate solution is TD($\lambda$), which updates every $\lambda$ fraction of the total number of iterations per epoch. Therefore, pure TD can be seen as TD(0) and Monte Carlo as TD(1).

An informative example of TD learning is explained [here,](https://earthlyabhijay.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/easy-21-assignment-1-monte-carlo-control/) by the means of simplified BlackJack robot.

Comment: Epoch would be a full 'game', start to end. An Episode is 1 round of playing. So let's say a game of blackjack consists of four 'hits' and then a 'stick' and a reward. In that case the Epoch consists of a total of five Episodes.

In my previous answer I mentioned the 'total number of iterations per epoch'. This was slightly confusing, the word 'iteration' should have been replaced by 'episode'.